# Why doesn't my cursor in Windows 7 show up on both monitors at the same time?

Tags: windows-7, mouse, cursor, mouse-cursor

My computer is currently set up with two monitors in extended desktop mode.

If I place my cursor between two monitors in Windows 7 I can only see the mouse on one monitor or the other.

It seems like if I move my mouse left or right one pixel, my mouse will jump from one monitor to the other.

Why won't Windows display my cursor on both screens at the same time?

Comment: p.s. This isn't really a problem, I'm just curious.

Comment: You will see it on both screens if you happen to be dragging a window at the time.

Comment: @Andrew, Yeah! I do!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Blame your video driver and/or video card. The cursor is hardware-accelerated, but nothing is being done to show the cursor on other displays. Only the "active" display shows it, and if it happens to not *all* be on the display then so be it.

Comment: So, the active display is the display where my mouse is?

Comment: Wherever the "hotspot" of the cursor is, yes.